Joomla 5 sql query custom field - pull logged in user's id number?
So I have a joomla 5 site that I'd like to add a custom field when someone is posting a new article. The custom field will have a list of titles of other articles they have published in another category in a drop down list.
I'm using the sql query field under the backend editor for the custom fields. Whenever I try to call the function to grab the USERID I've found, into that box, it crashes the form to submit the article in either the front end or backend specifically saying I have an issue in that query, where I've tried to put the call to get the logged in user's userid.
Is there any way to put something just in the query* box under the Articles: Edit Field to just pull the user id?
I've tried using just [user-id] in the field area, and calling some of the joomla factory calls in the query* field, but they all produce the same thin and crashes the form when trying to create and article to test. This is using only joomla 5 articles custom fields, no extra ACF plugins or components added.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
